# Cargar textos de la BD en un input para modificar laravel

Tags: laravel-5

tengo una pregunta ya que empiezo a investigar y no doy aun con la respuesta. Quiero que en mi vista que tiene varios input se cargue el texto que esta en mi base de datos y que se cargue en un div o algo asi la previsualizacion de una imagen que está en mi base de datos de manera que pueda ver que hay para asi modificar, hasta ahora solo tengo una vista y un controlador vacio ya que no se por donde podria empezar ( como podran notar llevo apenas como 3 dias con laravel jaja pero bueno a los golpes es que uno aprende xD )

mi vista (home.blade.php)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> 
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-feJI7QwhOS+hwpX2zkaeJQjeiwlhOP+SdQDqhgvvo1DsjtiSQByFdThsxO669S2D" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Inconsolata" rel="stylesheet">
    <style type="text/css">
        html {
             height: 100%;
             width: 100%;
        }
        body {
            background-color: #f6fafa;
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            margin-top: 0px;
            font-family: 'Inconsolata', monospace;
        }
        #cont {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            background-color: #0099FF;
            
        }

        #side {
            background:  #0c5460;
        }

        #side2 {
            background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
        }

        #btn-cus {
            border-radius: 0.5rem;
        }

        .col-2 {
                padding-right: 1px;
        }
        </style>

</head>
<body>

    <div class="row" id="cont">
        <div class="col-2" id="side">
                <div class="container">
                        <div class="row justify-content-center">
                                <img src="./img/logo.png" style="width:5rem; height:5rem; margin-top: 2.5rem; margin-bottom: 1.5rem;"/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row justify-content-center" style="margin-bottom: 3rem;">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">CERRAR SESIÓN</button>
                        </div>
        
                        <div class="row justify-content-center">
                                <button type="button" ID="btn-cus" class="btn btn-primary"; style="width: 93%; margin-bottom: 0.3rem; padding: 10px;">PAGINA/SECCIONES</button>
                        </div>
        
                        <div class="row justify-content-center">
                                <button type="button" ID="btn-cus" class="btn btn-primary"; style="width: 93%; margin-bottom: 0.3rem; padding: 10px;">AGREGAR TOURS</button>
                        </div>
        
                        <div class="row justify-content-center">
                                <button type="button" ID="btn-cus" class="btn btn-primary"; style="width: 93%; margin-bottom: 0.3rem; padding: 10px;">LOGIN/PASS</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-10" id="side2">

            <div class="container" style="background-color: #e3e6e9; margin-top: 1rem; height:95%; padding: 2rem 1rem 1rem 1rem;">
                <div class="container" style="background-color: #f0f3f5; height: 100%; border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px;">

                    <!-- TITLO -->
                    <div class="row justify-content-between" style="box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.47);
                                                                            border-radius: 5px;
                                                                            background: #f0f3f5;
                                                                            padding: 0.7rem 0.2rem 0.2rem 0.2rem;">
                        <div class="col-6">
                            <h4 style="color: #0b4650;"><strong>HOME/EDIT</strong></h4>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-6" style="text-align: right; padding-right: 3rem;">
                            <p style="color:gray;">ÚLTIMA EDICIÓN 24/02/2018</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <!-- ___________________FORMULARIO___________________ -->
                    <form method="POST" action="{{ route('home') }}">

                        <!-- BOTONES GUARDAR / CERRAR -->
                        <div class="row" style="    text-align: right;
                                                    margin-top: 1rem;
                                                    margin-bottom: 1rem;">
                            <div class="col-12">
                                <button type="button" class="btn" style="background: #065e6e; color: white; width: 7rem;">CERRAR</button>
                                <button type="SUBMIT" class="btn" style="background: #00a751; color: white; width: 7rem;">ACTUALIZAR</button>
                            </div>    
                        </div>

                        <!-- TITULOS -->
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-6" style="padding-left: 3px; margin-bottom: 1rem;">
                                <input type="text" placeholder="PRIVATE EXCURSSIONS IN SANTIAGO DE CHILE" style=" width: 100%;   padding: 0.3rem;   background: #e3e6e9;
                                                                                        border: solid 1px #8181825c;" text="PRIVATE ESCRUSSION IN SANTIAGO DE CHILE">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-6" style="padding-right: 3px; margin-bottom: 1rem;">
                                <input type="text" placeholder="Titulo Español" style="width: 100%; padding: 0.3rem;  background: #e3e6e9;
                                                                                    border: solid 1px #8181825c;">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <!-- DESCRIPCION -->
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-6" style="padding-left: 3px; margin-bottom: 1rem;">
                                <textarea name="message" rows="30" cols="80" style=" width: 100%; padding: 0.8rem;  height: 10rem; background: #e3e6e9; border: solid 1px #8181825c;">The primary objective of Pikun Mapu is to provide innovative and unique travel experiens fot the best value showcasing the most spectacular places, attractions and activities in Santiago de Chile</textarea>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-6" style="padding-right: 3px; margin-bottom: 1rem;">
                                <textarea name="message" rows="30" cols="80" style=" width: 100%; padding: 0.8rem;  height: 10rem; background: #e3e6e9; border: solid 1px #8181825c;">Texto Español</textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <hr/>
                        
                        <!-- CARGAR IMAGENES -->
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-6">
                                <h4>IMÁGENES DESKTOP</h4>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-6">
                                <h4>IMÁGENES MÓVIL</h4>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-6">
                                <input type="file" id="files" name="files[]" />
                                <br />
                                <div style="width: 5rem; height: 5rem;">
                                        <output id="list"></output>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-6">
                                <input type="file" id="files" name="files[]" />
                                <br />
                                <output id="list"></output>
                            </div>
                        </div>

        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
            function archivo(evt) {
                var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object
           
                // Obtenemos la imagen del campo "file".
                for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
                  //Solo admitimos imágenes.
                  if (!f.type.match('image.*')) {
                      continue;
                  }
           
                  var reader = new FileReader();
           
                  reader.onload = (function(theFile) {
                      return function(e) {
                        // Insertamos la imagen
                       document.getElementById("list").innerHTML = ['<img class="thumb" src="', e.target.result,'" title="', escape(theFile.name), '"/>'].join('');
                      };
                  })(f);
           
                  reader.readAsDataURL(f);
                }
            }
           
            document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', archivo, false);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

El controlador vacio con sus metodos index, store, etc etc y la ruta la declare asi Route::get('home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

ademas tengo mi modelo que es el siguiente que en ella introducire todos los textos de titulos, descrion e imagenes en mi base de datos si se que no es lo mejor todo asi pero bueno :/ y claro, luego metere todo el css en el archivo y eso pero mi preocupacion y objetivo es hacer lo que anteriormente les comente, si tienes alduna documentacion o me pueden asesorar bienvenido sea :D

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateSectionsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('sections', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('titu_1_ing');
            $table->string('titu_1_esp');
            $table->string('desc_1_ing');
            $table->string('desc_1_esp');
            $table->string('fond_1_dsk');
            $table->string('fond_1_mbl');

            $table->string('titu_2_ing');
            $table->string('titu_2_esp');
            $table->string('desc_2_ing');
            $table->string('desc_2_esp');
            $table->string('fond_2_dsk');
            $table->string('fond_2_mbl');

            $table->string('titu_3_ing');
            $table->string('titu_3_esp');
            $table->string('desc_3_ing');
            $table->string('desc_3_esp');
            $table->string('fond_3_dsk');
            $table->string('fond_3_mbl');

            $table->string('titu_4_ing');
            $table->string('titu_4_esp');
            $table->string('desc_4_ing');
            $table->string('desc_4_esp');
            $table->string('fond_4_dsk');
            $table->string('fond_4_mbl');

            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('sections');
    }
}
```